# dyld: could not load inserted library, but works on Simulator and another iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, dyld

So i was coding on my app the last few hours and on some point I decided to launch my app on my iPhone 8 (13.3.1) instead of using the simulator (13.3) and it crashed instantly with the following error:

```
dyld: warning: could not load inserted library '@executable_path/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib' into hardened process because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/SmartBuy
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8559B38-6434-4B39-BA14-DF1FF9689517/SmartBuy.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1
```

I tested the same app on my iPhone 5S (12.3.1) and it launched without any errors even tho I had a black-screen (My App is iOS 13 based)
some research suggested that it is because of certificates errors, but i cant seem to get around it. So here i am.

What I already tried:
Restart XCode, iPhone and MacBook
New Project with same code files
Deleted Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
New developer certificates
Delete folders like Cache and DerivedData
codesign in Terminal
reinstalled all Pods

Comment: Have you tried with any earlier iterations of iOS 13? Do you have a device that you can push an earlier version of iOS 13 to that you can test?

Comment: @JohnAyers I only got my iPhone 5S on iOS 12.3.1, but i could test it on my Dad's phone this afternoon.

Comment: I'm not claiming that this will solve your problem, but I'm curious if there is a bug within iOS 13.3.1 here, or if it is something else

Comment: It worked on 13.3.1 before. I just assume that something "corrupted" some librarys on my phone that cause this issue.

Comment: I exactly had the same problem which got fixed like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64876821/6681300)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be everywhere since 13.3.1 update.
I found some thread saying that it's got fixed by commenting `use_frameworks!`

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/128435
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051#issuecomment-580003683

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Now that i know that it is OS related, i can happily continue coding using Simulator