# dyld: Library not loaded: code signature invalid

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to build and run an application that uses the AVFoundation framework ...

*( I know that this is duplicate, but the solutions posted elsewhere doesn't help me.)*

I build successfully but the app crashes when I re-run it from Xcode with the following error:

```
> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
Referenced from : /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B9B93BB2-F55E-4DAE-A720-0F2D22A47278/FaceMarks.app/FaceMarks
Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B9B93BB2-F55E-4DAE-A720-0F2D22A47278/FaceMarks.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVfoundation.dylib:

>code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B9B93BB2-F55E-4DAE-A720-0F2D22A47278/FaceMarks.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVfoundation.dylib'

> lldb
```

The complete error message :

[image]

I have found many solutions, I have tested many of them but all of those not worked for me:

> 1. Clean, build and run an application

> 2. Set "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to "Yes" under the Build Settings > Build Options

> 3. Restart Xcode

> 4. Restart the phone

> 5. Reinstall the Xcode

> 6. Testing other simple application on my iPhone ( App contains just a print function )

> Note: **That the test app works fine on the simulator but on my iPhone it gives the same error**

dyld: **Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib**

[image]

Comment: You should really copy and paste the actual errors themselves, not screenshots (and _definitely_ not _pictures of your screen_)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm using a Mac of a friend , I didn't have a time to just copy the error , I will try to update the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771796/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftavfoundation-dylib)

Comment: I have seen this answer, but it does not work, I have mentioned in the post that I have tested many solutions but any of those worked for me.

Comment: Looks like there is a legitimate issue with free apple developer accounts using external frameworks as of iOS 13.3.1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60101963/4608154. However, I'm not sure this applies here since the framework you're using isn't external.

Comment: @wilc0 I think that was my problem, Thanks for you reply ,unfortunately there is no solution for this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error by using a paid developer account.

Comment: Upgrading to iOS 13.4 and Xcode 11.4 currently solves this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60101963/3167040

Answer (score 2):

Code signing issues are usually account related, so if you're using a free Apple dev account that carries certain limitations and expiration issues with it.

Firstly, make sure you have a valid and active developer account logged into Xcode under:

```
Xcode | Preferences | Accounts
```

Alternatively remove the developer account shown there and add it back in again.

Secondly make sure that the account specified under Preferences | Accounts matches what you have selected for your project target under:

```
<TargetName> | Signing & Capabilities
```

Comment: The developer account that I have created is free ( not a paid developer account ). Did you agree that this may be causing the error?

Comment: Every week, I was able to install the application because the free account developer gives me only 7 days to test, but it works and it did not give me any error, so the last week I have updated my iPhone X, ( security updates for ios 13.3.1 ), after updates, the apps crash every time after update, I have removed it and I tried to install again ( build and re-run ) from Xcode, Today I get encountered this error.

Comment: Yes, code signing issues are usually account related, so I wouldn't be surprised if your free account had some sort of a limitation or an expiration.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the solution for that? Create a new developer account did solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For all those still looking for a solution, I have a free dev account and solved it like this:

The problem is that you must first "trust" your account on your iPhone, and trust apps made from this developer.

See instruction with screenshots here:
[https://entirefaq.helpdocs.com/mobile-apps/iphone-app-how-to-fix-the-untrusted-enterprise-developer#:~:text=Tap%20Settings%20%3E%20General%20%3E%20Profiles%20or,prompt%20to%20confirm%20your%20choice](https://entirefaq.helpdocs.com/mobile-apps/iphone-app-how-to-fix-the-untrusted-enterprise-developer#:%7E:text=Tap%20Settings%20%3E%20General%20%3E%20Profiles%20or,prompt%20to%20confirm%20your%20choice).

Answer (score 0):

Even with the paid developer account, I had to include the **$(inherited)** in the linker flags at the top. This actually did the trick. Secondly, I started having this issue in the release enterprise build, the reason was the certificate was not trusted to I had to add the **Certificate Authority** relevant to that certificate to make it valid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `-deep` signing flag? It can cause this problem.

See "`--deep` Considered Harmful".

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/129980
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/128166