# How to prevent app from crashing when firebase installed

Tags: ios, firebase

I was working on an app and had no problem testing on an actual device but now my device won't run any xcode project on my phone if it has firebase.

I made a new project and ran it in sim, and it worked. I ran that same project on my phone, and it worked.

Then I added firebase to it (made app in firebase console, imported plist to app, added .configure() to app delegate, and successfully connected with Firebase. Runs in the simulator just fine.

When I run it on my phone this is what I get:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp1YP.png)

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Free developer accounts can’t run apps with embedded frameworks on iOS 13.3.1. There are a few questions on SO about this

Comment: SO is StackOverflow. As I said, this change happened with iOS 13.3.1. It is unclear if it is a bug that Apple will correct in the next release or a permanent/intentional change. You can comment the `use frameworks` line in your pod file and see if that fixes it. It isn’t firebase specific. It affects any embedded frameworks with iOS 13.3.1 and an unpaid membership

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994746/dyld-could-not-load-inserted-library-but-works-on-simulator-and-another-iphone/60471665#60471665

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. I ended up getting the membership. It works, thank you very much! Weird how they would do that.