# iOS app will run on the Xcode Simulator but not on my iPhone because of dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dyld

When trying to run my app in the Xcode simulator it runs successfully, but when I try to run my app on my iPhone this is the error message I keep getting:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  

Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback: 
code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback: 
code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback: 
stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback: 
code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback: 
code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAFEEAC3-7D4A-4188-926A-5E90DEF449BC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AvailableHapticFeedback.framework/AvailableHapticFeedback: stat() failed with errno=1
```

I'm currently using Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)
I've tried:

- Clean Build Folder
- Restarting Xcode
- Restarting the MacBook
- Restarting the iPhone
- Trying it    on an iMac
- Updating the MacBooks operating system
- Xcode is up to    date.
- Checked Runpath Search Paths: $inherited
                       @executable_path/Frameworks
                       @loader_path/Frameworks
- Build Options - Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries = YES
- Deleting    the Derived Data folder and trying again.
- Clearing out my Keychain
- My Apple Development certificate is set to    'Use System Defaults'
- I've downloaded the AppleWWDRCA.cer and    installed it.
- I've tried updating the pod file and installing those again.

I've also run the following commands in Terminal:

rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

- In the Target > General Build Settings > Frameworks, Libraries, and
  Embedded Content I have Pods_MyApp.framework, under 'Embed' I've
  changed it from 'Do not embed' to 'Embed & Sign', neither were
  successful.
- I tried adding the AvailableHapticFeedback framework    explicitly in
  the 'Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content', but    Xcode
  complains of a duplicate, so removed it.
- I've made sure there is no value in the Packaging section -
  'Executable Prefix'

Can anyone suggest anything else to help me fix this issue, please?

Comment: Does the solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994746/dyld-could-not-load-inserted-library-but-works-on-simulator-and-another-iphone work for you?

Comment: Thank you, but no it didn't work.  From what I've read on that forum post it could be a bug with iOS 13.3.1

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid][1] Can't comment. But this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
The solution, for my case, was to properly embed the Framework.

In the main project root file, select your app target and change the Framework embed property from "Do Not Embed" to "Embed & Sign".
In my case, this worked.

[image: EmbedFrameworkImage]